# ReactJs handling routing while integrating with API

Tags: java, reactjs, rest, http, dropwizard

I have a webapp with ReactJS as frontend and dropwizard java backend.
all methods of REST API backend are in the path
`http://localhost:8080/api`
The react have routes like /login /signup

when I run the reactJs frontend separately the routes

```
http://localhost:3000/login
http://localhost:3000/signup
```

can be navigated directly.

when I run the backend with fronted by using [configurable-assets](https://github.com/dropwizard-bundles/dropwizard-configurable-assets-bundle) the main page works and in main page I have link to /login, /signup component which also works as expected.
The problem in when I directly access

```
http://localhost:8080/login
http://localhost:8080/signup
```

it doesn't work and says 404 not found.

investigating further I found that in the react build generated directory if I add directory like login signup and have index.html file over there its able to render that index.html file.

My question is what is the recommended way of solving this

- one way would be to run the frontend separately
- other would be to change the backend route somehow to point it to React routes

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know ho to do this in java, but the idea is that you need to return the index.html file on every request besides API requests.

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer If we start returning the index.html files then the reactjs would not be used as all logic would start migrating on that index.html?

Comment: The index.html should import the javascript file and thus do all the react logic.

Comment: For all the routes except `/api` you must be returning index.html file

Comment: @ShubhamJain Do you know how the server and react will integrate in that case?

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer wouldn't returning multiple index.html against react principle, do you know any sample react application that interacts with a REST server like that

Comment: @animeshsharma on your backend you would have to handle that if route is not /api send the same index.html file to client

Comment: @ShubhamJain I meant different routes in react have different component and  there is only one index.html in react, how should one send multiple index.html if there is only one?