# React convert function component to class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, i18next, react-i18next

I am using the react `react-i18next` package for language translation.

The function component that I have works correctly without any error

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

function MyComponent() {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

  return (<Suspense fallback="loading">
           <h1>{t('Welcome to React')}</h1>
          </Suspense>);
}

export default MyComponent;
```

when I tried converting this to a class as below

```
import React, { Component, Suspense } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
        return (
        <Suspense fallback="loading">
            <h1>{t('hello')}</h1>
        </Suspense>
        );
    }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

I get the error

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a >function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

Can someone point me to what am I doing incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useTranslation` is a `hook` and can only be called from within a `function` based component. For `class` based components use the `HOC`

```
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

class Comp extends Component{
    render(){
        const { t, i18n } = this.props

        return <SomeJSX />
    }
}

export default withTranslation()(Comp)
```

**Note** You can also use `withTranslation` in functional components.

Comment: totally unrelated, any inputs on this would be really helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57663407/reactjs-handling-routing-while-integrating-with-api?noredirect=1#comment101775902_57663407